# If $X$ and $Y$ are objects of $\mathrm{Set}$, is there any reason not to regard $\mathrm{Hom}(X,Y)$ as an object, too?

Tags: soft-question, category-theory

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ denote objects of $\mathrm{Set}$. Is there any reason not to say: therefore, $\mathrm{Hom}(X,Y)$ is *itself* an object of $\mathrm{Set}$? Furthermore, is there any reason not to write $Y^X = \mathrm{Hom}(X,Y)$ and/or $Y^X \cong \mathrm{Hom}(X,Y)$?

A good answer should probably mention the following concepts.

1. The internal/external distinction.
2. [Exponential objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_object); and what, if anything, is the difference between $\mathrm{Hom}(X,Y)$ and $Y^X,$ (specifically in the case where $X$ and $Y$ are objects of $\mathrm{Set}$.)
3. The [principle of equivalence](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/principle+of+equivalence).

Comment: I don't get the question. It is a set, hence an object of the category of sets. Is there anything to discuss here?!

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, so you're saying that writing $Y^X = \mathrm{Hom}(X,Y)$ is acceptable, in your opinion?

Comment: I think the notation $Y^X$ or $(-)^X:\mathcal C\to \mathcal C, Y\mapsto Y^X$ is used in general if this is a functor which is right adjoint to the product functor $(-)×X: Z\mapsto Z×X$. In $\mathbf{Set}$ if $Y^X=$Hom$(X,Y)$ then this is the case.

Comment: This is the trivial case of "enriched category".  In other words, a Set-enriched category is nothing but an ordinary category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathrm{Hom}(X,Y)$ is a set. Together with the evaluation map ($\mathrm{Hom}(X,Y) \times X \to Y$), it is also *an* exponential object, because it satisfies [the definition of one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_object). However, a consequence of the definition of exponential objects is that, if they exist, [they are unique up to (unique) isomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_property) (not equal, but more than just isomorphic). So we tend to write $Y^X$ to mean *any* (fixed) object (together with an implicitly defined evaluation map) of this form, and say words like "*the* exponential object", understanding implicitly that there are many, but they are all naturally isomorphic, so all have the same properties.

Comment: Okay. I'm satisfied.

Comment: It suddenly occurs to me that if we want $\mathrm{Hom}$ to be a functor $\mathrm{Set}^\mathrm{op} \times \mathrm{Set} \rightarrow \mathrm{Set}$, we'd *better* have $\mathrm{Hom}(X,Y)$ denote an object of $\mathrm{Set}$.